# How can i get API Key for Demo Magento EE account

Tags: api, user-roles, user, key

How i can get API Key for Magento EE Demo. I searched it can be get by creating Role and User for web service in the System-->Web service menu but there in no Web service sub menu for system in Demo account. Then how can i get API Key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're using http://enterprise-admin.user.magentotrial.com/index.php/admin/

This is a demo site, Web Services and lots of other functionalities are hidden from public users!

For creating Webservices Role & User for testing purpose, you can download Magento Community Edition & install it in your server or localhost (using xampp/wamp), then create Role and User.